# How do I create a single horizontal bar between two specifc points on the x-axis in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have conducted some SPM analysis on a set of gait data, the results show where significant differences occurs across stance regions.

I would like to create a singular horizontal bar that is shaded between the regions where sigficance is identified similar to that in [this](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0169834) paper - that is a black block bar between two x-axis locations (indicating the percentage of stance significant difference occurs).

I have managed to produce a something close to what I am after with the following code for one example where significant difference occurs from 20% to 100% of stance:

```
y = 'SPM{t}'
x = [0,100]
plt.figure(figsize = (6,1))
plt.axvline(x=20.466, color='black',linewidth='2', linestyle='-')
plt.axvline(x=100, color='black',linewidth='2', linestyle='-')
plt.xlabel('Stance (%)', size = (12))
plt.barh(y,x, color ='white')
```

[image: Code output]

This provides me with the region between the two lines as the region I want to display, however I would like this to be filled in black. The y-axis is arbritary as it is has no numerical value. Effectively I want the graph to indicate on and off periods across the x axis with black bars indicating 'on' (sig diff) and space between indicating 'off' (no sig diff).

I appreciate there is probably a very simple solution, however I am new to Python.

Any help/guidance would be great.

OC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to plot another bar with `left`:

```
y = 'SPM{t}'
x = [0,100]
x1,x2 = 20.466, 100
plt.figure(figsize = (6,1))
plt.xlabel('Stance (%)', size = (12))
plt.barh(y,x, color ='white')  

# this 
plt.barh(y,width=x2-x1, left=x1, color='k')
```

Output, not perfect but visually acceptable (to me):

[image]

Comment: `plt.axvspan(x1, x2, color='k')` could be an alternative